# NSComboBox to display duplicate items in different colors

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a NSTableView with 5 columns. One of the column has NSComboBoxCell. Combo box is populated with the name of files of one type (say jpg) from a directory. I keep the file names in NSArray in alphabetical order. I populate the combo box cell with file names array as follows:

```
[assayCell addItemsWithObjectValues:(NSArray *)fileNameArray];
```

Earlier there was only one type of files but now same directory has multiple types of file with same name eg. image1.jpg and image1.png. I want to populate file names without extensions in combo box. Files with different extensions are to be shown in different color eg. jpg file will be in black color and png will be in green color.

I am comparatively new to cocoa/Obj-C so I don't find a proper way to achieve this. How to keep duplicate items in a array? Should I use NSDictionary to store name of file and its extension and then make array of dictionaries. In that case how will I sort my array?

Please suggest a solution...

Regards
Abhijeet

Comment: Use NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! Only doubt is can I sort an array of NSDictionary the same way as I was sorting an array of NSStrings. I am sorting the array of NSStrings as: NSArray *sortedArray = [assayNameList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Determining* the colour to use depends on how you store the file extensions. If they are part of the filename (i.e. "image1.jpg"), you will have to separate them. If they are separate already (i.e. like you mention, in a dictionary with two kvps) then I guess you're good.

*Applying* the colour could be achieved using NSAttributedString:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *astr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello!"];
    [astr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                 value:[NSColor redColor]
                 range:NSMakeRange(0, astr.length)];
    [assayCell addItemWithObjectValue:astr];
```

Comment: Thanks! Only thing is because the file names are with out extension so at the time of combo box item selection how do I identify type of the file. Should I retrieve the color of the selected item and use it to identify the type of file? Is it possible?

Comment: Well in theory you could do that but it'll probably turn out messy and is also error-prone, i.e. if later on you decide to change colouring scheme you'll have to change filetype identification code etc... I'd suggest maintaining a list of filenames and corresponding extensions at all times, and base drawing of your UI lists on that.

Comment: Please make sure you accept an answer if it is helpful to you. This way it will not show up as unanswered and you will increase your chance of getting future questions that you post answered.

Comment: Thanks! Your answers are helpful to me. I already voted them useful. Sorry but how to accept an answer?

Comment: There is a faint tick mark under the answer score. You can click it to accept an answer. Take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as well.

Comment: I have populated my NSComboBoxCell with NSAttributedString now to show different file types in different color. Earlier there were only NSStrings in my combobox so I was autocompleting the text by subclassing NSComboBoxCell and overriding (NSString *)completedString:(NSString *) method. How can I do the same for NSAttributedString now?

Comment: @Abhijeet I would encourage you to ask this in a new question, since it covers a separate topic.